# JavaFX TextArea remove default undo action for shortcut Ctrl+Z

Tags: java, javafx

I am trying to make an editable Java FX TextArea, that doesn't have the ability to undo the last step with shortcut Ctrl+Z. By default, when you create an editable JavaFX `TextArea`, JavaFX provides the default undo/redo functionalities for the shortcuts Ctrl+Z/Ctrl+Y while that TextArea is focused (as well as copy, paste etc.). I would like to disable these default actions for the Shortcuts Ctrl+Z and Ctrl+Y to be able to create my own undo/redo logic instead of the default logic provided by JavaFX. Also: I don't want to disable the undo redo logic from JFX completely, since I am using it afterwards, (`textarea.undo()` and `textarea.redo()` must still be possible) I simply want to remove the KeyPress Events that are created by default, how can I do this?

Code: I've created a TextArea inside a BorderPane with FXML, and attached a Controller to the FXML, so the TextArea can be accessed by code, no css file is used.

Comment: Mind you, it seems these shortcuts are platform specific.  On Ubuntu 16.04, Ctrl-Y doesn't appear to do anything, redo is Ctrl-Shift-Z. (just tested this)

Comment: @Arjan Thanks, that's good to know but a tricky one to work around, there could be other platforms with other configurations. best would be to have the shortcuts configurable by a property file...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### **You have several options:**

The common thing is that they are using the [comsume()](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/event/Event.html#consume%28%29) method of the `Event` class.

**1) Using [KeyCodeCombination](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/input/KeyCodeCombination.html):**

```
TextArea ta = new TextArea();
final KeyCombination keyCombCtrZ = new KeyCodeCombination(KeyCode.Z, KeyCombination.SHORTCUT_DOWN;
final KeyCombination keyCombCtrY = new KeyCodeCombination(KeyCode.Y, KeyCombination.SHORTCUT_DOWN);
ta.setOnKeyPressed(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {

    @Override
    public void handle(KeyEvent event) {
        if (keyCombCtrZ.match(event) || keyCombCtrY.match(event) ) { 
            event.consume();
        }

    }
});
```

**2) Using [isShortcutDown()](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/input/KeyEvent.html#isShortcutDown%28%29) method of [KeyEvent](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/input/KeyEvent.html):**

```
TextArea ta = new TextArea();
ta.setOnKeyPressed(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {

    @Override
    public void handle(KeyEvent event) {
        if ((event.getCode() == KeyCode.Z || event.getCode() == KeyCode.Y)
            && event.isShortcutDown()) {
            event.consume();
        }

    }
});
```

Comment: "Control" is not the correct modifier, though; it will not work on a Mac. You should use "Shortcut", which is platform-independent.

Comment: Accepted for providing multiple solutions, both tested and working for my case.

Comment: @James_D Thanks for this helpful advice, so i have done this wrong several times before.. :-)

Comment: Thanks for the correction @James_D, the answer is updated now.

Comment: @DVarga Please also correct the first part: it's KeyCombination.SHORTCUT_DOWN not  KeyCombination.CONTROL_DOWN as i've suggested in the edit..

Comment: How to do this using fxml?

Answer (score 4):

Add an event filter to the text area and consume the event if it matches the shortcuts:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyCode;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class TextAreaNoUndo extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        TextArea area = new TextArea();
        area.addEventFilter(KeyEvent.ANY, e -> {
            if (e.getCode() == KeyCode.Z && e.isShortcutDown()) {
                e.consume();
            }
        });

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(area));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```